# Installing ROS from binaries and Gazebo from source

Tags: ros, gazebo, binaries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everybody,
I need to run multiple turtlebots and get access of the Gazebo source code so that I can control the turtlebots. Currently I have installed both hydro ROS  and 1.9 Gazebo from pre-compiled binaries. To get access the Gazebo source code I need to reinstall Gazebo from the source. My question are: Do I need to reinstall both ROS and Gazebo from the source in order to keep them working properly? or Do I just need to reinstall Gazebo from the source.
Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.
Robert

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155591/installing-ros-from-binaries-and-gazebo-from-source/) by [Robert1](https://answers.ros.org/users/12391/robert1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you install gazebo from source. You need to install anything that depends on it from source as well. You can still use binary ROS packages which are not related to gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0